# Timeout error - rescue in rbuf_fill (Engineyard)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, engineyard

My website has been up and running for a while on engineyard. Today, all of a sudden, I have been getting this error. This continuosly occured for about 5 to 10 minutes and then seems ok now. Any idea what causes this ? Also, any suggested cleanup or settings ? As such, there is no unusual activity on the website.

A Timeout::Error occurred in home#index:

```
  Timeout::Error
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:140:in `rescue in rbuf_fill'
```

---

### Backtrace:

```
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:140:in `rescue in rbuf_fill'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:134:in `rbuf_fill'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:116:in `readuntil'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:126:in `readline'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2219:in `read_status_line'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2208:in `read_new'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1191:in `transport_request'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1177:in `request'
  rest-client (1.6.7) lib/restclient/net_http_ext.rb:51:in `request'
  newrelic_rpm (3.4.2.1) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/net.rb:22:in `block in request_with_newrelic_trace'
  newrelic_rpm (3.4.2.1) lib/new_relic/agent/method_tracer.rb:242:in `trace_execution_scoped'
  newrelic_rpm (3.4.2.1) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/net.rb:21:in `request_with_newrelic_trace'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1170:in `block in request'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:627:in `start'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1168:in `request'
  rest-client (1.6.7) lib/restclient/net_http_ext.rb:51:in `request'
  newrelic_rpm (3.4.2.1) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/net.rb:22:in `block in request_with_newrelic_trace'
  newrelic_rpm (3.4.2.1) lib/new_relic/agent/method_tracer.rb:242:in `trace_execution_scoped'
  newrelic_rpm (3.4.2.1) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/net.rb:21:in `request_with_newrelic_trace'
  /data/webinterface/shared/bundled_gems/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/api_client-b950641bfce6/lib/api_client/api.rb:15:in `get'
  /data/webinterface/shared/bundled_gems/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/api_client-b950641bfce6/lib/api_client/show.rb:15:in `recommended'
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:229:in `set_public_home_page_params'
  app/controllers/home_controller.rb:14:in `index'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:469:in `_run__141284936__process_action__119629849__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:205:in `process_action'
  activerecord (3.2.3) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  newrelic_rpm (3.4.2.1) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/rails3/action_controller.rb:34:in `block in process_action'
  newrelic_rpm (3.4.2.1) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/controller_instrumentation.rb:268:in `block in perform_action_with_newrelic_trace'
  newrelic_rpm (3.4.2.1) lib/new_relic/agent/method_tracer.rb:242:in `trace_execution_scoped'
  newrelic_rpm (3.4.2.1) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/controller_instrumentation.rb:263:in `perform_action_with_newrelic_trace'
  newrelic_rpm (3.4.2.1) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/rails3/action_controller.rb:33:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:600:in `call'
  omniauth (1.1.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:177:in `call!'
  omniauth (1.1.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:157:in `call'
  omniauth (1.1.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:177:in `call!'
  omniauth (1.1.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:157:in `call'
  omniauth (1.1.1) lib/omniauth/builder.rb:48:in `call'
  /data/webinterface/shared/bundled_gems/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/exception_notification-192a49a02d63/lib/exception_notifier.rb:19:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `context'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:200:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:338:in `call'
  activerecord (3.2.3) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
  activerecord (3.2.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:467:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
  activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__857894770__call__169073287__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:245:in `fetch'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:185:in `lookup'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:66:in `call!'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
  /usr/libexec/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/request_handler.rb:96:in `process_request'
  /usr/libexec/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:513:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
  /usr/libexec/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:274:in `main_loop'
  /usr/libexec/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:206:in `start_request_handler'
  /usr/libexec/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:171:in `block in handle_spawn_application'
  /usr/libexec/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:479:in `safe_fork'
  /usr/libexec/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:166:in `handle_spawn_application'
  /usr/libexec/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
  /usr/libexec/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
  /usr/libexec/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:180:in `start'
  /usr/libexec/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:129:in `start'
  /usr/libexec/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:253:in `block (2 levels) in spawn_rack_application'
  /usr/libexec/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:132:in `lookup_or_add'
  /usr/libexec/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:246:in `block in spawn_rack_application'
  /usr/libexec/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:82:in `block in synchronize'
  <internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
  /usr/libexec/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:79:in `synchronize'
  /usr/libexec/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:244:in `spawn_rack_application'
  /usr/libexec/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:137:in `spawn_application'
  /usr/libexec/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:275:in `handle_spawn_application'
  /usr/libexec/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
  /usr/libexec/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
  /usr/libexec/passenger/bin/passenger-spawn-server:101:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

My bad. The reason for this was because I had introduced a sleep for a few minutes in one of the controllers as I wanted a delayed execution. I think this caused the problem